# A machine has 2 NICs. Which one will be utilized when connecting to a socket?

Tags: sockets

Suppose I create a very simple socket connection, how can one programatically:

1. Find out what interface (ip address
   / NIC) is being used.
2. Force the other interface

Comment: You need to specify a programming language and operating system if you want your question to be answered.

Comment: Agreed, this is simple to do in most languages, but you need to specify what you are working in.

Comment: are you connecting or listening?

Comment: @Rich: the OP talks about "sockets".  Doesn't that always mean BSD sockets, which are implemented in basically the same way on every platform?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Um. If you think Java, C#, and C all handle sockets the same way, you are doing something very wrong.

Comment: Oh.  I had assumed that socket libraries in most languages essentially wrap the BSD sockets interface (bind(), accept(), listen() etc.), since everyone's doing TCP/IP these days.  Are you telling me that Java/C# don't have bind() and accept()?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Of course they /have/ them, but you would be stupid to use them as opposed to the higher level abstractions.

Comment: ...unless you wanted to do something fairly low level, such as bind a particular NIC, right?  A high-level abstraction that lets you bind a particular NIC is not a high-level abstraction IMHO.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Where are you getting this idea that you cannot control which interface you use at the higher level??

Comment: From a quick glance at the Java docs for DataSocket, they have bind(), plus constructors that call bind() for you.  I guess you could say a ctor that calls bind() for you is higher level, but I'll stand by my original assertion that TCP/IP sockets work in basically the same way in any language.

Comment: Maybe C# is completely different though, I haven't looked.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: One more time. You wouldn't use bind. Since you pointed out Java, you would use ServerSocket(int, int, java.net.InetAddress) or something similar. But again, you can bind to a specific interface. So yes language matters here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whatever language you are using, you will ultimately be using a sockets library layered on top of an implementation of the original **BSD sockets** C networking library.  Although you may need to change some things for different libraries and languages, the following information should at least be helpful in targeting where to look in your library's documentation.

### Servers

Normally, a server program issues the following sequence of calls:

1. `socket()` returns a "floating" socket object.
2. `bind()` binds the socket to a particular well-known port number on (usually) all network interface cards (NICs) in the machine.
3. `listen()` causes the socket to go "live".
4. `accept()` blocks until a connection from a client machine is made.

The point where you can decide which NIC to use is in the call to `bind()`, which expects a data structure containing an IP address and a port number.  The usual strategy is to pass the special value `INADDR_ANY` for the IP address, indicating that connections should use any and all NICs in the machine, however a particular NIC's IP can be specified instead to receive connections only via that NIC.

### Clients

Normally, a client program issues the following sequence of calls:

1. `socket()` returns a "floating" socket object.
2. `connect()` binds the socket to a randomly selected port on a randomly selected NIC and attempts to connect to the remote `host:port` combination specified.

So how can a client choose what NIC to use?  A client can also choose to call `bind()` if it so desires, after `socket()` and before `connect()`.  Usually this isn't done simply because `connect()` will automatically bind an unbound socket in a way that enables access via any NIC (which is usually the desired behaviour), but this auto-binding  can be turned off by calling `bind()` explicitly.  In this case, you should specify 0 for the port number to have the OS choose a random port number for you.

Once a connection has been made, you can call `getsockname()` to get information about the socket, such as which IP it is bound to (i.e. which NIC it is communicating through) and what port number was assigned (in the case of a client program).

Answer (score 2):

a. After a connection is established, most socket APIs have a call for something like "getLocalAddress" that will tell you the interface that the OS selected for you.

b. Similarly, after a socket is created but before a connection is established, most socket APIs have a call to bind the socket to a local address and/or port.

Answer (score 1):

You will find these links usefull, since the question doesn't provide a language, here's for the most common ones.

[Socket Programming in C](http://www.uwo.ca/its/doc/courses/notes/socket/)

[Socket Programming in C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3918/socket-programming-in-c-part-1/)

[Socket Programming in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html)

[Socket Programming in Python](http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/sockets/)

So, use any of these links and go to the languge you are using. Find the function for getting your host address or ip address and use the Bind method for the appropriet language. This will force the application to bind to that interface.