# Java server on a machine with two NICs

Tags: java, sockets, nic

If I write a java socket server on a machine with two LAN Cards each of which is on a different network like one is on the 10.x.x.x network and the other is on the 192.168.10.x network, is the server going to bind to one of them randomly or it will listen to the incoming requests on both NICs and answer accordingly?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428313/a-machine-has-2-nics-which-one-will-be-utilized-when-connecting-to-a-socket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not specify adapter it will listen on all available adapters.